# MY RPlidar stopped spinning and sending data

Tags: ros, arduino, rplidar, spinning

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i have an Arduino Leonardo and the RPLidar. I also have a RGB shield attached to it. I got the liar to spin on windows but have recently just changed to macintosh and it isn't spinning anymore. The code loads in fine through arduino but there is no output just 0's. /Users/williamphoenix/Desktop/Screen Shot 2015-07-07 at 11.23.37 AM.png Here is a screen shot of my error on my program.

I also have loaded many others onto the board and none of them seem to get the liar going and spitting back data.

Thank you

Sorry Just Starting out on this and trying new things

Idk how else toe the image into the blog it says that i need 5 of something.

The error is /Users/williamphoenix/Documents/Arduino/libraries/RPLidarDriver/RPLidar.h:56:10: note: no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Serial_' to 'HardwareSerial&' no matching function for call to 'RPLidar::begin(Serial_&)'

As well as i have loaded a few of the Arduino written libraries into my Arduino leonardo which is connected to my RPlidar and it doesn't spin anymore but the green LED is lighting up along with the board is responding but the liar will not spin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213056/my-rplidar-stopped-spinning-and-sending-data/) by [Will Phoenix](https://answers.ros.org/users/23080/will-phoenix/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-07-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-07-10**:
can you please host the image somewhere else? also, please provide a more thorough explanation of the error, so that we might be able to help.

**Comment by [Will Phoenix](https://answers.ros.org/users/23080/will-phoenix/) on 2015-07-13**:
Sorry Just Starting out on this and trying new things

Idk how else toe the image into the blog it says that i need 5 of something.

The error is /Users/williamphoenix/Documents/Arduino/libraries/RPLidarDriver/RPLidar.h:56:10: note: no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Serial_' to 'HardwareSeria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Every time I open the serial of my rplidar here without the ROS node it does the same, it stops spinning.
I guess there the serial adapter somehow controls the reset line using the hardware signals `RTS/CTS`.

You should maybe check to not interfere with them, maybe the reset line of the LIDAR is pulled to
reset or not connected or has a lose contact...

---

If you use them seperately (e.g. USB serial interfaces):

Maybe you opened the wrong serial I guess Arduino and RPLidar register to the same kind of device names
**/dev/ttyACM**0 (maybe your Arduino Software opened the one of the RPLidar)

Replug both and check with `dmesg` which one is Arduino and which one is RPLidar

Regards

Christian

---

Originally posted by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) with karma: 1376 on 2015-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0